# Does logical AND and NOT exists in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, formal-languages

Is there NOT logic in ANTLR? Im basically trying to negate a rule that i have and was wondering if its possible, also is there AND logic?

Answer (score 17):

@larsmans already supplied the answer, I just like to give an example of the legal negations in ANTLR rules (since it happens quite a lot that mistakes are made with them).

The negation operator in ANTLR is `~` (tilde). Inside lexer rules, the `~` negates a single character:

```
NOT_A : ~'A';
```

matches any character except `'A'` and:

```
NOT_LOWER_CASE : ~('a'..'z');
```

matches any character  except a lowercase ASCII letter. The lats example could also be written as:

```
NOT_LOWER_CASE : ~LOWER_CASE;
LOWER_CASE : 'a'..'z';
```

As long as you negate just a single character, it's valid to use `~`. It is **invalid** to do something like this:

```
INVALID : ~('a' | 'aa');
```

because you can't negate the string `'aa'`.

Inside parser rules, negation does not work with characters, but on tokens. So the `parse` rule:

```
parse
  :  ~B
  ;

A : 'a';
B : 'b';
C : 'c';
```

does **not** match any character other than `'b'`, but matches any token other than the `B` token. So it'd match either token `A` (character `'a'`) or token `C` (character `'c'`).

The same logic applies to the `.` (DOT) operator:

- inside lexer rules it matches any character from the set `\u0000..\uFFFF`;
- inside parser rules it matches any token (any lexer rule).

Comment: Hi, do you know know to write a rule to match simple strings but not specific keywords? I tried to write rules like this one below (but it doesn't work at all)
STRING: ~('\r' | '\n' | '\t' |  ' ' | 'keywords')

Comment: Your example, NOT_LOWER_CASE : ~LOWER_CASE;
LOWER_CASE : 'a'..'z'; does not work in Antlr4. I get "rule reference LOWER_CASE is not currently supported in a set"

Comment: @baruchl my answer is for ANTLR3, not ANTLR4. So in v4 you just do this: `NOT_LOWER_CASE : ~[a-z]; LOWER_CASE : [a-z];`

Answer (score 11):

ANTLR produces parsers for [context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) (CFLs). In that context, `not` would translate to complement and `and` to intersection. However, [CFLs aren't closed](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Context-free_language#Nonclosure_under_intersection_and_complement) under complement and intersection, i.e. `not(rule)` is not necessarily a CFG rule.

In other words, it's impossible to implement `not` and `and` in a sane way, so they're not supported.